# GNUPG - Creating a subkey in a single command

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp

With the following commands:

```
gpg --edit-key [KEY]
gpg> addkey # Add a new key
gpg> 4 # RSA (Sign only)
gpg> 4096 # Keysize
gpg> 0 # Expiration
gpg> y # Correct?
gpg> y # Really create?
```

I'm able to create a subkey, i would like to perform this with a single command, is this possible?

Can't seem to find any information on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr:

```
gpg \
    --pinentry-mode=loopback \
    --passphrase="" \
    --quick-add-key $KEYID rsa4096 sign 0
```

Explanation:

- The [`--quick-add-key`](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/gpg/gpg.1.en.html#quick-add-key) option takes between 1 and 4 space-delimited arguments:

  - `fpr`: the "fingerprint" of existing private key
  - `algo`: the desired algorithm for the new subkey
  - `usage`: the desired usage kind for the new subkey
  - `expire`: the desired expiration date or duration for the new subkey
- The [`--passphrase`](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/gpg/gpg.1.en.html#passphrase)`=""` disables passphrase protection on the new subkey.
- The [`--pinentry-mode`](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/gpg/gpg.1.en.html#pinentry-mode)`=loopback` must (since version 2.1) be used in conjunction with `--passphrase` to avoid the interactive prompt.

I tested this with GnuPG version 2.2.40 on Debian Bookworm.